# How to dis-select in muli-edit mode of notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I know this is a simple question, but surprisingly I cannot find another person asking the similar question after some search. The multi-edit function (by pressing ctrl + left mouse click) is convenient, but it is annoying when you click the last click wrong and find that you have to re-select all position again. So, is there a way to dis-select in multi-edit mode of notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

I think currently there is no better answer from the following one: it is not currently possible.

However, in cases if you need to select **entire lines**, you can do that easily:

1. Using **Ctrl+F2** mark/unmark* lines (for mass marking, use **Mark** tab of **Find** dialog with **Mark Lines** option checked). Mouse: click left margin where blue marks appear.
2. Using menu **Search > Bookmarks** operate with marked lines

*) possility to unmark lines is dis-select you are asking about